# magento2 one step checkout order summary item subtotal not display

Tags: magento2.3, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout, order-summary, subtotal

Item subtotal not display in one step checkout page. please see attached image.
[image]

Please help me why item subtotal not display here?

```
<!-- ko if: isPriceExclTaxDisplayed() && getRegion('row_excl_tax') -->
<span class="price-excluding-tax" data-bind="attr:{'data-label': $t('Excl. Tax')}" data-label="Excl. Tax">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('row_excl_tax') --><!-- /ko -->
</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Price excluding tax call when I see in inspect element.

What will be the cases here why row total not display?

ANSWER:

Hi there
I had the same problem. After some research I noticed that Magento_Wee module is creating these two regions (row_incl_tax and row_excl_tax). I had disabled the Magento_Weee module because I don't need it. But this resulted in both regions that where there but empty. The template checks only if the getRegion() returns something. And that it does! It returns an Empty Array. So by Adjusting this file: `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal.html` and change its contents to:

````
    <!-- ko if: isPriceInclTaxDisplayed() && getRegion('row_incl_tax') && getRegion('row_incl_tax').length < 1 -->
    <span class="price-including-tax"
          data-bind ="text: getValueInclTax($parents[1]), attr:{'data-label': $t('Incl. Tax')}">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: isPriceInclTaxDisplayed() && getRegion('row_incl_tax').length > 0 -->
    <span class="price-including-tax" data-bind ="attr:{'data-label': $t('Incl. Tax')}">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('row_incl_tax') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: isPriceExclTaxDisplayed() && getRegion('row_excl_tax') && getRegion('row_excl_tax').length < 1  -->
    <span class="price-excluding-tax"
          data-bind ="text: getValueExclTax($parents[1]), attr:{'data-label': $t('Excl. Tax')}">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: isPriceExclTaxDisplayed() && getRegion('row_excl_tax').length > 0 -->
    <span class="price-excluding-tax" data-bind ="attr:{'data-label': $t('Excl. Tax')}">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('row_excl_tax') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>```
````